# "k ef" throwing exception in Visual Studio 2015 Package Manager Console

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to the Package Manager Console.  I have managed to install the KVM and am trying to create a migration in my ASP.NET 5 app.

When I run "k ef" I get the following exception:

```
k.cmd : System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
At line:1 char:2
+ k <<<<  ef
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.Argument...cannot be null.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Parameter name: appEnv
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IApplic
ationEnvironment appEnv, ILibraryManager libraryManager)
```

I'm in the correct folder, and I  have run `kpm restore`. I'm at a loss.

Comment: What KRE version are you using and what EF package version?

Comment: The default is `KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1` and I have EntityFramework.SqlServer 7.0.0-* and EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-*

Comment: Please update to KRE beta3 and try again. Beta1 is super old

Comment: Running `kvm upgrade` it says that the latest version is already installed

Comment: There were lots of changes between Beta1 and Beta3. Even `kvm` changed so you will need the latest version. `kvm upgrade` does not upgrade the `kvm` itself. Go to the Home repo to get the latest `kvm` https://github.com/aspnet/home/

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci It looks like I had Beta3 installed all along - I was originally looking at the `.kre` folder rather than the `.k` folder

Comment: I found the issue.  I was installing EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-*.  When I changed it to 7.0.0-beta3, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching dependency for `EntityFramework.Commands` from `7.0.0-*` to `7.0.0-beta3` made it work.